# tf.placeholder(tf.random_normal([3,1]), name='weight') -> error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
(tensorflow / python3.6) tf.placeholder(tf.random_normal([3,1]), name='weight') -> error
```

As it's written on the title, I got an error from

```
W = tf.placeholder(tf.random_normal([3,1]), name='weight')
```

When I input it, I got an error message which is

[image: error message]

Please, let me know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, do not post code or error messages as images. Copy and paste them, so your questions is better searchable. [See this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a placeholder's shape and type, but you can't set its initial content. If you want W to contain a 3-by-1 tensor of floats, you can use this code:

```
W = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3, 1), name='weight')
```

To set a placeholder's value, you need to use the `feed_dict` argument in the session's `run` method.